# Cross checking query on the same table

Tags: sql-server

How do I write a query to display records where `sample1_id = 3` and `sample2_id = 5`  or `Sample1_id = 5` and `sample2_id =3`.

Meaning it should check the row of `sample1_id` and see wherever there is a record of 5 in line with `sample2_id` having a record of 3 and also checked if `sample1_id` is having a record of 5 line with `sample2_id` having a record of 3.

I hope my question do make sense

[image]

Comment: Some sample data with the desired results would have been clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Just going by what you have provided, a mock statement would look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE (sample1_id = 3 AND sample2_id = 5)
   OR (sample1_id = 5 AND sample2_id = 3);
```

If this is not correct, please provide some sample data and a sample of the results you would like.

Added the following in response to question about using variables:

```
DECLARE @intId1 int,
        @intId2 int;

SET @intId1 = 3;
SET @intId2 = 5;

BEGIN;
    SELECT *
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE (sample1_id = @intId1 AND sample2_id = @intId2)
       OR (sample1_id = @intId2 AND sample2_id = @intId1);
END;
```

Comment: what if i want to replace the numbers with variables, how will i do it? cos i might not know the number the user will pass, so i think its best i replace it with variables

Comment: Updated to show using variables. Depending on where you are using this from: internal to sql server, or from an external application - you will need to look into how you want to populate those variables.

Comment: from an external  application, dreamweaving. using the results on a webpage

Comment: That is outside of the scope for your question. You will need to follow the recommended/established patterns for executing remote sql from your language/platform of choice. You would just use the query I posted above replacing the numbers with your variables. You can do that with bind variables or by concatenating the values into the query string before executing it. The former is the better way to go.

Comment: the first answer works fine, but you cannot assign one variable to two or more columns for example where sample1_id = MMColParam AND sample2_id = MMColParam2 or sample1_id = MMColParam AND sample2_id = MMColParam2. When i do that the url becomes sample1_id=3&sample2_id=5&sample1_id=5&sample2_id=3 and it reads wrong application values. I hope you get me. if we can talk in a chat there's something i'd like to show u

Comment: You would do it the following way: "(sample1_id = MMColParam AND sample2_id = MMColParam2) OR (sample1_id = MMColParam2 AND sample2_id = MMColParam)". I don't see any reason that would not work.

Comment: when i test that in the sql box it works, but when i execute it in the web browser it executes this way (sample_page.asp?sample1_id=3&sample2_id=5&sample1_id=5&sample2_id=3), and it gives me the error. Wrong application Value. but anyway thanks for the help offered me. i'm grateful

Comment: You can't reassign the values in your query string, you need to just use the same variables swapped in the SQL statement. Read my previous comment and look at the variable placement.